# NodeJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user-agent' of undefined

Tags: node.js, user-agent

Im getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user-agent' of undefined
    at /home/ubuntu/node/server.js:312:154
```

At line 312 I have this code:

```
var p = require('ua-parser');
console.log(p.parseUA(spark.headers['user-agent']).toString());
```

Any ideas how to avoid the error? Its causing forever to restart.

**Edit**

```
var p = require('ua-parser');

primus.on('connection', function (spark) {

    spark.on('register', function (data) {
        console.log(p.parseUA(spark.headers['user-agent']).toString());
    });

 });
```

Comment: Where is `spark` defined in your code?

Comment: updated with the code. `spark` comes from the npm `primus`

Comment: Does `spark.headers` exist right inside the 'connection' handler function (before `spark.on('register', ...)`? If not, does `spark.request.headers` exist?

Comment: this does not happend everytime, only when headers is not set for some reason

Comment: Are the primus connections cross-origin/cross-domain when the `headers` doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error indicated. "spark.headers" is "undefined".

If the headers is not set, it is "undefined" and accessing a property of it will cause the exception.